# Condition for all even numbers to be prime

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, propositional-calculus

If $2^2<0$, then all even numbers are prime. Is this a true statement?

An even number $n$ can be written as $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. In order for $n$ to be prime its only divisors should be $1$ and $n$, but I don't see why this is the case.

Comment: If a proposition $P$ is false then the statement $P\implies Q$ is vacuously true, regardless of $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $P\implies Q$ is equivalent, by definition, to $(\lnot P)\lor Q$. In your case, $\lnot(2^2<0)$ is true. Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 2):

The statement "If $2^2<0$, then all even numbers are prime" is defined as meaning "Either it's false that $2^2<0$, or it's true that all even numbers are prime."

In other words, when a mathematician **says** "If $2^2<0$, then all even numbers are prime," what they **actually mean** is "Either it's false that $2^2<0$, or it's true that all even numbers are prime." They're speaking a sort of "mathematical English" which isn't quite the same as everyday English.

In any case, it *is* false that $2^2<0$, which means that this sentence is true.